# Metodos de Ruby Rails en Modelo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Soy nuevo en Ruby Rails y estaba intentando hacer un metodo en un modelo Client.rb que recupere de una tabla clients algunas columnas y al que pueda acceder desde el controller.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

´
´
-

def mi_metodo
    Client.select("first_name, last_name")
end
´
´
´
´

end



class ClientsController < ApplicationController

def index

    @data = Client.mi_metodo

end


end
```

Esto no funciona,
¿Como hacer metodos que devuelvan consultas SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Debes definirlo como método de clase, tampoco es necesario llamar a `Client.select` dentro del método, ya que va implícito para cualquier método de clase. Al final queda algo como:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    def self.mi_metodo
        select("first_name, last_name")
    end
end
```

luego ya puedes llamar a `Client.mi_metodo`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de los scopes de rails, la idea de estos es definir sentencias en métodos de clase, por ejemplo:

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  scope :find_by_complete_name -> (param1, param2) { where(first_name: param1, last_name: param2) }
end
```

y para llamarlo en el controlador solo basta con declarar la clase seguido del scope:

```rb
Client.find_by_complete_name("first_name", "last_name")
```

Para mas información puedes visitar https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes